# SQL query which converts sets or range of records on the basis of record before and after rows of that range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion

Suppose this table

```
Day Present Absent  Holiday
1/1/2019    1   0   0
1/2/2019    0   1   0
1/3/2019    0   0   1
1/4/2019    0   0   1
1/5/2019    0   0   1
1/6/2019    0   1   0
1/7/2019    1   0   0
1/8/2019    0   1   0
1/9/2019    0   0   1
1/10/2019   0   1   0
```

I want to mark all holidays zero which are between absents, if an employee is absent before and after the holidays, then holidays will become absent days for him. I don't want to use a loop, I want set base query approach.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected results for your data above? CAn you also please format your sample data so that it's nicely aligned? You can't tell when one column starts and another ends with the correct version. Thanks.

Comment: i could not be able to generate any kind of set base script, except loop, well loop through all records and find those holidays which are in between absents

Comment: i want to implement one payroll policy which is that, when an employee is absent before and after public holiday then consider those holidays as absent to deduct his salary,

Comment: That doesn't really address my comment above. You need to edit your question so we can help you.

Comment: i have on approach but no idea how to implement that, which is, update @table set Holiday=0, Absent=1 where Holiday=1 and Absent=0 and (last row before holiday sequence)=absent and (top row after holiday sequence)=absent

Comment: @Larnu please dont down my question, i am weak in english, so cannot explain you clearly, but that above table is my raw table,

Comment: *"@Larnu please dont down my question"* I haven't. But you *still* need to supply that consumable sample data and expected results, **and** you're attempt(s) which I've asked for above; and I suspect your lack of supplying that information (even after being asked) is why this has been downvoted by another user.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: simple i want those rows of holidays=1 which are in between Absents=1

Comment: By "show the results" people are asking for you to [edit] into your question how the result data should **look** - instead of explaining it using words which is hard to understand even if English was your first language - we say the same thing to all question askers, show us some sample starting data, and show us the result data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As a `select`, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when prev_absent = 0 and next_absent = 0 and holiday = 1
             then 0 else holiday
        end) as new_holiday
from (select t.*,
             lag(absent) over (order by day) as prev_absent,
             lead(absent) over (order by day) as next_absent
      from t
     ) t;
```

If this does what you want, then you can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when prev_absent = 0 and next_absent = 0 and holiday = 1
                   then 0 else holiday
              end) as new_holiday
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(absent) over (order by day) as prev_absent,
                   lead(absent) over (order by day) as next_absent
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
update toupdate
    set holiday = new_holiday
    where holiday <> new_holiday;
```

EDIT:

You can also do this with `join`s:

```
select t.*,
       (case when tprev.absent = 0 and tnext.absent = 0 and t.holiday = 1
             then 0 else holiday
        end) as new_holiday
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tnext.day = dateadd(day, -1, t.day) left join
     t tnext
     on tprev.day = dateadd(day, 1, tprev.day)
```

Comment: I am using sql 2008, Lag is not support in that version

Comment: please give me CTE example which runs in sql2008

Comment: @QuaperClient . . . You should upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Sir through CTE can i find those rows, which are in between two rows of Absents where Holiday=1